# jQuery AJAX inserts everything into DB... BUT the image?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So, everything works fine if I insert my form info with pure PHP, everything inserts into my DB including the –input "type/file"– (meaning, the image too).

But when it comes to insert it via AJAX, it inserts everything BUT the image. For some reason the image is the only thing I can't get to insert when it comes to doing it via AJAX. Here's my code.

AJAX CALL

```
$('#insert_form').click(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'insert_form_backend.php',
            data: $('#__form__').serialize(),
            success: function() {
                alert("Insert Successful");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

insert_form_backend.php

```
<?php

require_once "mysql/db.php"; 

$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];

$photo = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
$photo_temp = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
$photo_path = "folder_temp_images/$photo";
move_uploaded_file($photo_temp, $photo_path);



$query = "INSERT INTO my_table(column1, column2) ";
$query .= "VALUES ('$column1', '$column2')";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

?>
```

As I said above, it ONLY inserts everything (including image) if I submit the form with pure PHP, meaning, it refreshes the whole page.

Thanks, I don't want to throw in the towel on this, I really want to make this with ajax. I hope we could fix this!

FOR FILE IN AJAX try this method:

```
$("#photo").change(function(){
    var file_datta = $('#photo').prop('files')[0];   
    var form_datta = new FormData();                  
    form_datta.append('file', file_datta);                       


    $.ajax({
                    url: 'insert_form_backend.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
                    dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: form_datta,                         
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(php_script_response){
                    }
         });
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried checking what the ajax is posting to ensure everything is there?

Comment: `$column1', '$column2'` what are those supposed to represent? you have 2 text inputs and 1 file input. The question's unclear in more ways than shown.

Comment: May have to pass as FormData... more reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825913/how-to-pass-file-data-with-ajax-and-jquery

Comment: @Matt I think everything is there, since if I remove the ajax to switch it to php submit it does work everything. Is so weird, I've been 2 days breaking my head on this.

Comment: @Ed91gg but have you actually checked using `var_dump($_POST)`? Just because it works one way doesn't means it's definitely being sent

Comment: .serialize() can't handle files.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes, those are html inputs, didn't post the html, thought it could be clear to understand with the information above?

Comment: @KevinB Didn't know that, can you post any link or comment the right way to handle images? Thanks for that piece of info, didn't know that.

Comment: Yup, i marked it as a dupe. you can use FormData to send both the files and the other inputs.

Comment: Didnt read the two links I posted? They explain using FormData to pass files with form data through ajax. ***sigh***

Comment: @IncredibleHat Yes, I'm actually on that and getting it pretty good, thanks!

Comment: @KevinB Sorry for that, thanks, might delete this question then! Good day!